# Open PDF file from the html table in php coding file

Tags: php

Kindly help me to open pdf file as hyperlink. I have put output in attached image.
Actually I want to provide rights to admin user able to open uploaded file from the table. Candidate uploaded his resume in html form and when admin log in, he will see all data in table format. Now I am able to give link uploaded file in above table as "uploads/78.pdf" and "uploads/Shivchalisa.pdf" but not able into table under column 'File Uploaded'. I think You understand what I have problem

open pdf file in table
[image]

Comment: Everyone can post code, it's kind of the point of the site. What happens when you try? Do you get any error message or something? While adding the code, you should also add much more details about the actual issue. What happens? Where are you stuck? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. But you have to provide us the code you have to let other people understand what you have

Comment: _"I think You understand what I have problem"_ - No we don't since "not able to" isn't an explanation of what actually happens, nor is it the code you're having issues with. Again, You _must_ post all relevant code together with a _proper_ explanation. Please read the links I posted in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `ps_add_weblink` — Adds link to a web location
- `ps_add_launchlink()` - Adds link which launches file
- `ps_add_locallink()` - Adds link to a page in the same document
- `ps_add_pdflink()` - Adds link to a page in a second pdf document

**Description**:

```
ps_add_pdflink ( resource $psdoc , float $llx , float $lly , float $urx , float $ury , string $url ) : bool
```

**Parameters**:

- `psdoc` -- Resource identifier of the postscript file as returned by ps_new().
- `llx` -- The x-coordinate of the lower left corner.
- `lly` -- The y-coordinate of the lower left corner.
- `urx` -- The x-coordinate of the upper right corner.
- `ury` -- The y-coordinate of the upper right corner.
- `url` -- The url of the hyperlink to be opened when clicking on this link,
  e.g. http://www.php.net.

**Returns**:

- Returns `true` on success or `false` on failure.

**Reference**:

[Php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ps-add-pdflink.php)

Comment: Sorry not able to understand: I have used code                                               
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   
 
        
  
      echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row["Firstname"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["Middlename"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["Lastname"]."</td>
           <td>".$row["Intdate"]."</td>
           <td>".$row["Appliedfor"]."</td>
           <td>".$row["email"]."</td>
           <td>".$row["Fileupload"]."</td>

Comment: More easy: echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$text.'</a>'."<br><br>";

Comment: You might want to point out that those functions aren't bundled with the normal PHP releases and that you need to install the PostScript-extension using PECL before they are available. But honestly, I think the question is too unclear to know what they _actually_ are asking about, which makes any answer just random stabs in the dark at this point.

Comment: You tried to change the column from
<td> ". $ Row [" Fileupload "]." </td>
by
<td><a href='.$row["Fileupload"].'>Example Text</ a></td>

Comment: I m going to reply jose cristian that how it possible in echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$text.'</a>'."<br><br>";because I need to match url with table row which I want to learn.